# HTML SetAttribute with nested properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setattribute

I'm sure this is answered somewhere, but it is my lack of terminology knowledge that can't find where to look.

I am dynamically creating some Html as a result of some json data loaded from the server.

I am using createElement, and setAttribute to create the html and append it to the main body.

However, my dynamic html contains a "data-" attribute, which has further nested properties. An example end goal is such:

```
<li>
   <span class=item data-item='{"width": 100, "height": 100, 
    "properties": { "Name": "foo", "Surname": "bar" }}'></span>
</li>
```

I have had some success when running:

```
li.setAttribute("data-item", '{"width": 100, "height": 100, "properties": 
                 { "Name": "foo", "Surname": "bar" }}');
```

But then when I come to use the data item elsewhere in my java-script, the attributes are recognized as a string as opposed to an object. When I hard code the HTML, the data-item is loaded correctly as an object. I have made the assumption it must be because I am incorrectly setting this attribute.

Comment: How do you access the attribute? Are you sure you get an object when reading it from hard-coded HTML? Afaik, HTML attributes are **always** strings

Comment: If you access the data attribute using jQuery's `data()` method, it will deserialise the JSON for you. Otherwise you'll need to do it manually, as the two answers below show.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think the OP is using Vanilla JS not JQyery. but I agree with your views.

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal their example is, however they tagged the question with jQuery, so thought I'd offer the alernative

Comment: I managed to solve my problem by the suggested answers. When using JSON.parse(), I had an error that my string was not in JSON format, turns out I was missing a closing brace. Always the simple things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a string because the property is set as a string, you can get the data as an object after parsing it like so:

```js
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.id = "li1";
li.setAttribute("data-item", '{"width": 100, "height": 100, "properties": { "Name": "foo", "Surname": "bar" }}');
li.innerHTML = "SAMPLE li";
document.body.appendChild(li);


var data = document.getElementById('li1').getAttribute('data-item');
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not answer the question title :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.parse to turn it into an object :

```
var result = JSON.parse('{"width": 100, "height": 100, "properties": { "Name": "foo", "Surname": "bar" }}');
// result.width => 100
// result.properties.Name => "foo"     etc...
```